# Extjs 4.2 How to add contextmenu to a Label at runtime?

Tags: dom, extjs

I have a label which created at runtime and I want to attach a listener to it to display a contextmenu when the user click right mouse button?

Thank you

Comment: Post some code, this is too little info to even guess.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

`mText` is a label.

```
mText.getEl().on('contextmenu', function(e,t,eOpts) {
    e.stopEvent();mnutxtContext.showAt(e.getXY());
});
```